# HTML PHP form with multiple fields

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a html form with 5 rows and 30 fields. Note the attached image. [image]

I have to capture all of these fields in an array to later convert to a csv file. Each field is labelled at follows: qt1, fa1, en1, et1, ba1, qt2, fa2, etc... Instead of taking each row and adding them to an array in php one at a time is there an easy(ier) way to accomplish this?

I can easily take each row and add them to an array the issue with this i feel would be the speed of the script and the fact that i will have to write 30 lines of array data in the php script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++): ?>
    <input name="qt[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
    <input name="fa[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
    <input name="en[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
    <input name="et[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
    <input name="ba[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
<?php
endfor;
?>
```

On the server side, you will receive all this data in your $_POST variable anyways, so it will all be in an array regardless. This has an advantage of saving all your values of the same row with the same index and all the same data types under one array.

Not sure about performance, but code readability and maintenance is alot easier like this.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you! Ill give it a try and post back if I have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Name the input fields like `input[i][j]` and you can access them later in php like: `$_REQUEST['input'][i][j]` as a multidimensional array.